# Change number of form inputs based on select value

Tags: javascript

I have a form formatted like so:
http://jsfiddle.net/E3DfA/

What I am trying to achive is so that when the value of the select changes, the number of form inputs changes.

I have searched around, but found nothing that really makes sense to me, I understand I will need to use ajax, but how would I go about this. A push in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use AJAX. You need to capture the `input` event on your the `select` element  and then generate the HTML code you want to display.

Have a look at the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library, the documentation contains may examples.

#### Edit

You were nearly there

```
$("select").change(function () {
      var str = "";
      var count = Number($("select option:selected").val())
      for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          str += '<div class="oneinput"> <label>' + i
                  + "</label> <input name='" + i + "'></input>"
                  + "</div>";
      }

      $("#text").html(str);
});
```

You used `.each` where you needed to use a `for`-loop. `each` iterates over arrays. 
​

Comment: Thank you that was a lot of help! if you see this now http://jsfiddle.net/E3DfA/3/ you will see that I have it to change, how would I make it so the inputs are shown from 1- whatever the value is?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this ?

Its very basic example :

[Basic example](http://jsfiddle.net/JwYTp/)

Comment: Hello, thats kind of what I am looking for but I wanted to stay away from switching visibility. if you see this now http://jsfiddle.net/E3DfA/3/ you will see that I have it to change, how would I make it so the inputs are shown from 1- whatever the value is?